# FFMPEG, any video to 16:9

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Help me find a command or script that will convert any video to 16:9, h264 and ~2500kbps. I have a server where people upload videos of different quality, size and length. It can be either 640x480 or 1216x2160. Ultimately, I need to get any resolution to 16:9 (with black borders, if needs) and bitrate without visible loss of quality, which will be acceptable for online broadcasting.

I have this command, but it does not check the resolution of the video. And if the video was 560x448 1000kbps and 700mb, then after conversion it will be 1280x720 3000kbps and 1.5gb, that's not right.

```
ffmpeg -i 5.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -vf scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1 -tune zerolatency highoutput.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following as a starting point:

```
ffmpeg -i "5.avi" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -vf "scale=w=trunc(ih*dar/2)*2:h=trunc(ih/2)*2, setsar=1/1, scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=1, pad=w=1920:h=1080:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=#000000" "output.mp4"
```

Please tweak the `crf` value depending on the picture quality.

Comment: I get an error on almost any file, my conversion stops https://justpaste.it/2ph36

Comment: ok, I tried to write this code for a 640x480 video, and it worked fine
but it works the same as my source code ffmpeg -i "1.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -vf "scale=w=trunc(ih*dar/2)*2:h=trunc(ih/2)*2, setsar=1/1, scale=w=848:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=1, pad=w=848:h=480:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=#000000" -report "output.mp4"

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.
So far as I know the `cur_dts is invalid` error is due to broken header or invalid timestamp in the AVI file and should have nothing to do with the scaling filter. Is it possible to point me to the url of the video footage so I can reproduce the error? BR.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`-vf scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1,pad='max(iw+mod(iw,2),2*trunc(ih*16/9/2))':'max(ih+mod(ih,2),2*trunc(iw*9/16/2))':-1:-1`